# wso2 bps Enabling SSO

Tags: wso2

I followed the [link](https://identity.cloud.wso2.com/carbon/sso-saml/docs/userguide.html) to enable SSO for BPS 3.2.0

adding the feature "Token based authenticator" to bps fails. Please advise

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: Token based authenticator Feature 3.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.token.feature.group 3.2.0) Missing requirement: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 3.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 3.2.0) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.compendium.feature.group [3.5.0.v20090413,3.6.0)' but it could not be found Missing requirement: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 3.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 3.2.1) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.compendium.feature.group [3.5.0.v20090413,3.6.0)' but it could not be found Missing requirement: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 3.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 3.2.2) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.compendium.feature.group [3.5.0.v20090413,3.6.0)' but it could not be found Missing requirement: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 3.2.3 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 3.2.3) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.compendium.feature.group [3.5.0.v20090413,3.6.0)' but it could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Token based authenticator Feature 3.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.token.feature.group 3.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.token.ui.feature.group [3.2.0] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Token based authenticator UI Feature 3.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.token.ui.feature.group 3.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group [3.2.0,3.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Saml sso components are packaged with bps itself. Therefore it is not required to install new features.

All listed jars below are included with the product.

```
org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso_4.2.0.jar
org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.common_4.2.0.jar
org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.stub_4.2.0.jar
org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.ui_4.2.1.jar
org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.stub_4.2.0.jar
org.wso2.carbon.sso.redirector.ui_2.2.0.jar
```